# I have a Netgear CM600 modem and an Asus AC68U router. I cannot figure out why I can't access the modem from behind the router

Tags: router, modem

**Modem: Netgear CM600**

- Address: 192.168.100.1

**Router: Asus AC68U**

- Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Address: 192.168.1.1

I've read through tons of articles about similar issues.

I've tried a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0, giving the computer a static IP, and more. All devices are hardwired. Yet, only when the pc is plugged into the modem directly can I access it. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: @Spiff - my bad, I've never seen anything like that, that wasn't also a router. Guess we just don't have them here, everything here is ISP-supplied, you don'y buy your own.

Answer (score 2):

Your cable ISP's network uses DHCP to assign your router a publicly routable IP address for its WAN port. It also tells your router to use the ISP's nearest router as its default gateway. So your router doesn't have a route to your modem's default static address/subnet. So when you try to send packets to 192.168.100.1, your router forwards them to your ISP's router, which probably drops them because the whole 192.168.0.0/16 subnet is reserved for private use and not routable to the public Internet.

If your router firmware lets you muck with low level network settings, you could give your router a static IP address of 192.168.100.2/24 on its WAN port, *and then set up additional NAT rules to handle that subnet,* and you'd be able to reach your modem. You would need to continue to run the DHCP client on the WAN port as well so it still gets a public IP address and valid default route, or else you'd break your route to the Internet.

**Edited to add** the phrase in italics mentioning needing NAT handling. Your modem won't have a route to your 192.168.1.1 subnet, so you need to make sure your router is making your traffic to 192.168.100.1 look like it's coming from 192.168.100.2. Thanks to @davidgo for the catch.

Comment: I could be wrong but my guess is this won't solve the problem by itself - you will also need to find a way to turn on NAT on the WAN interface.

Comment: @davidgo Ah, good catch. Fixed.